# Eloquent Javascript Looping over RegExp Matches

Tags: javascript, regex

The following [example](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html#p_zFHO63a2iV) is a bit confusing to me:

```
var text = "A string with 3 numbers in it ... 42 and 88.";
var number = /\b(\d+)\b/g;
var match;
while (match = number.exec(text)){
    console.log("Found", match[1], "at", match.index);
}
```

Specifically, I don't understand how this has a "looping" effect. How does it run through all the matches within one string if it keeps calling `match[1]`. Is there some kind of side effect with exec that I am unaware of?

**Edit:**
I still would like an answer to how `match[1]` is working.
How does `match[1]` produce any answer? When I test this type of thing myself, I get `undefined`, look

```
> var y = /\d+/g.exec('5')
undefined
> y
[ '5', index: 0, input: '5' ]
> y[1]
undefined
```

Whats going on here? Wouldn't it be y[0], or in the case above, match[0]? Like:

```
> y[0]
'5'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RegExp object remembers the last matched position with [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property.

Quoting [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Example:_Finding_successive_matches),

> If your regular expression uses the `"g"` flag, you can use the `exec()` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, **the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property** (`test()` will also advance the `lastIndex` property).

**Important Note:** The first part of the first line of the quoted section is important. `If your regular expression uses the`"g"`flag`. **Only if the RegEx has `g` flag you will get this behavior.**

Comment: Adding to that, when you add that `/g` to the regex you're _explicitly asking for this behavior_. If you remove the `/g` the behavior you find surprising is gone.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I left a note about it. Thanks :-)

Comment: @thefourtheye Okay, I can understand this. But you didn't really answer my question about `match[1]`.  How come its not `match[0]`.See my edited post please.

Comment: In the second case you don't have a capturing brackets. That is why `match[1]` is not there. In the first case you have `(\d+)` which is the capturing group.